# What to use to seal gaps between slate veneer on vertical exterior walls of home

Tags: masonry, caulk

I have slate veneer on the exterior walls of some parts of my home.  There are gaps between the various uneven pieces of slate which protrude off the wall to different levels (i.e. each slate piece has a different thickness).  What colored (the slate is black in color) tube caulk product would you recommend to seal these gaps?

Comment: Why do you believe that the gaps need to be sealed?  There is almost certainly one or more barriers underneath the slate. Caulking will spoil the aesthetics.

Comment: Because in the cabana, when it rains, the water is somehow penetrating through the gaps and I see evidence of the drywall in the utility closet getting water damage.  Thus, I thought that sealing some of the larger gaps at corners etc. might help prevent water penetration.  It is generally not an issue in most other places where we have used the slate as a veneer on top of concrete (e.g. retaining wall, foundation walls, etc)

Comment: I would want to see photos of the surface, the leaks could be coming from someplace else. Thermal cameras at a great tool for finding the source of leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 100% silicone from GE or DAP. Unfortunately, pure silicone has less color choices. Black might be blacker than your slate and look odd. Dark gray might look best, but I don't know if you can find it.